# how to implement multi page localization in static HTML pages using jquery and json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

In my home page I have dropdown list , in that dropdown list I have 3 options English , greek , jerman 
if I select greek option it should affect to the all the pages, english text should changed to greek (for example :- in index , about , contact pages )

by default I am using English language

Comment: Creating a multi lingual site is an extremely big job. Can you narrow down what you are trying to do in particular? If you need help doing the whole job then please search as start-to-finish tutorials exist for this already.

Comment: hi  Christian , if i change the language from english to greek in home page , in about page text should be change from english to greek , all i need to change is  text in pages

Comment: you will need a session variable which will be used across your website and the language will be set through that session variable

Comment: @SrinivasR how are you managing your content? is it just static html or is in it a database?

Comment: @Christian ,its just a static html pages , i am not using any database to retrieve the Content.

Comment: @SrinivasR Please post up your html. Always post code. Makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have stated in the comments that you have static HTML files and no database. You want to be able to select one of a few languages and have the text on the page change to match the language selected.

I wont write any new code on this as its been covered many times, but I will direct you to this tutorial. It will be trivial to change the nav to a drop down.

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/

Please ask any questions in the comments and I'll update the answer.